# Request not being processed

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, express-validator

Im currently trying to learn more about Express and Express-Validator but currently facing the following issue: When I'm starting the server and using Postman do excess one of the endpoints the response is not completed. However, it seems like the Validation Chain is being processed but afterwards nothing happens. I have the following modules:

index.ts

```
import {config} from 'dotenv';
import App from './api/app';
import ControlAmbilight from './api/routes/controlAmbilight';
import AdjustLightning from './app/AdjustLightning';

const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '..', '.env');
config({path: ENV_FILE});

const PORT = process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3000;

const ambient = new AdjustLightning();

const app = new App([
  new ControlAmbilight(ambient),
], <number> PORT);

app.listen();
```

app.ts

```
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import pino from 'pino';
import expressPino from 'express-pino-logger';
import errorMiddleware from './middleware/errorMiddleware';

export default class App {
    private logger: pino.Logger;
    private expressLogger;
    public app: express.Application;
    public port: number;

    constructor(controllers: any, port: number) {
      this.app = express();
      this.port = port;

      this.logger = pino({level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info'});
      this.expressLogger = expressPino({logger: this.logger});
      this.initializeMiddlewares();
      this.initializeControllers(controllers);
      this.initializeErrorHandling();
    }

    private initializeMiddlewares() {
      this.app.use(this.expressLogger);
      this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    }

    private initializeControllers(controllers: any) {
      controllers.forEach((controller: any) => {
        this.app.use('/', controller.router);
      });
    }

    private initializeErrorHandling() {
      this.app.use(errorMiddleware)
    }

    public listen() {
      this.app.listen(this.port, () => {
        this.logger.info(`Server running on ${this.port}`);
      });
    }
}
```

controlAmbilight.ts

```
import {Router, Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
import {ValidationChain, check, validationResult} from 'express-validator';
import AdjustLightning from '../../app/AdjustLightning';

// eslint-disable-next-line require-jsdoc
export default class ControlAmbilight {
    private ambient: AdjustLightning;
    // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
    public router = Router();
    public path = '/controlAmbilight';

    // eslint-disable-next-line require-jsdoc
    constructor(ambient: AdjustLightning) {
      this.ambient = ambient;
      this.initializeRoutes();
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line require-jsdoc
    public initializeRoutes() {
      this.router.post(this.path, this.controlValidator, this.setAmbilight.bind(this));
    }

  private controlValidator = (): ValidationChain[] => [
    check('on').notEmpty().withMessage('Field \'on\' is required'),
    check('on').isBoolean().withMessage('Field \'on\' must be type boolean'),
  ];

  // eslint-disable-next-line require-jsdoc
  private setAmbilight(req: Request, res: Response): void {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      res.status(422).json({error: errors.array()});
    } else {
      const isOn = (req.body.on == 'true');

      res.send(`The curent state is: ${this.ambient.getIsActive()}`);
    }
  }
}
```

I was hopping that someone could explain me what I'm missing here. It seems like I need to call express` next() middleware function, but I'm not sure where to implement it.

**EDIT**
As requested I'm adding the errorMiddleware:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import HttpException from '../exceptions/HttpException';

export default function errorMiddleware (error: HttpException, 
                    request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const status = error.status || 500;
    const message = error.message || 'Ups... This did not work :(';
    response
        .status(status)
        .send({ status,
                message });
}
```

And as an additional comment: When I'm adding the Validation Chain directly into the post method within `controlAmbilight.ts` like that:

```
public initializeRoutes() {
      this.router.post(this.path, [
        check('on').notEmpty().withMessage('Field \'on\' is required'),
        check('on').isBoolean().withMessage('Field \'on\' must be type boolean'),
      ], this.setAmbilight.bind(this));
}
```

It is working as expected.

Comment: Code looks ok - could it be that `errorMiddleware` is hit, and that you don't handle the response there? Can you add the code for that?